# Creating a small size label

Tags: java, itext

I need to make a small label (1.75 long and 0.75 high) that contains just three lines using iText. Problem is whenever I add `Chunk.NEWLINE` to document, it instead of moving me to the next line, moves me to next page. This is because of small page size.

How can I restrain all my text to be on same page but just on next line?

```
Float width = 126.4725f; // 1.75 in
Float height = 54.2025f; // 0.75 in

Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(width, height);
document = new Document(pageSize, 5f, 55f, 2f, 180f);
specimenPDF = new File("specimenLabel_"+reqID);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(specimenPDF));
document.open();
Paragraph specimenInformation = new Paragraph();
document.add(new Chunk(string1, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 2, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)))));
document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
document.add(new Chunk(string2, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 2, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)))));
document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
document.add(new Chunk(string3, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 2, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)))));

specimenInformation.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
document.add(specimenInformation);
document.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues.

First, you have a document that's 54 units tall and you want iText to use 2 of those units for a top margin and 180 of those units used for a bottom margin giving you -128 units for horizontal space. It seems like you are giving coordinates instead of widths which is what iText is expecting. You'll know better than me but I'd change it to something like:

```
document = new Document(pageSize, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f);
```

Second, you've got a `Paragraph` but you aren't using it and are instead writing directly to the document. I'd recommend actually using the `Paragraph`:

```
Paragraph specimenInformation = new Paragraph();
specimenInformation.add(new Chunk(string1, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 2, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)))));
specimenInformation.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
specimenInformation.add(new Chunk(string2, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 2, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)))));
specimenInformation.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
specimenInformation.add(new Chunk(string3, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 2, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(new Color(0, 0, 0)))));
```

Last, you need to tell iText how tall a "line" is which is done by the [`Leading`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Phrase.html#setLeading(float)) property. You can set this directly in the constructor for `Paragraph`. Below I'm setting it to the same size as your font.

```
Paragraph specimenInformation = new Paragraph(2);
```